# Remove or edit a synthetic.conf file in etc/

Tags: macos

I have a Mac in which the user has placed a synthetic.conf file in etc/
The file contains an entry for home creating a synthetic link to some directory. This makes it unbootable. Normally the computer is running Catalina. I can boot it using a Mojave startup that was still on the drive. I have admin privileges.

I would like to delete or edit that file. I can't even find it. This problem is beyond me.

Comment: When you say you can't find it - do you mean you can see inside that folder & it's not there even showing invisibles, or you're struggling to track even the folder location?

Comment: RE: " I can boot it using a Mojave startup that was still on the drive." -- What exactly do you mean but this? What is a  "Mojave startup"? Are you actually booting to a user's **Desktop** on  **macOS Mojave** or are you booting to **macOS Recovery** for **macOS Mojave**? Can you boot to **macOS Recovery** for **macOS Catalina**?

Comment: I set the finder to show all files, but I can't get into (or find) the catalina beta etc/ directory. I can see the Mojave etc/
I'm in over my head here. I struggle to even describe the problem.

Comment: Regardless, have you tried using the `find` _command_? E.g. `find / -type f -name 'synthetic.conf'`

Comment: @user3439894 I was able to choose a Mojave startup at boot time. I did try exactly that find command. I get a lot of Permission denied messages for /Volumes/catalina beta

Comment: I'm curious...(1)how do you know that `synthetic.conf` is actually there, and (2)what makes you think this file is the cause?  Simply putting a `.conf` file in `/etc/` doesn't change things - something has to *read* it and that service has to crash to make it non-bootable.  Let's see if it boots in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting).  Then, let's go from there.

Comment: Allan - it was put there this morning, followed by a reboot. It makes (I'm told) a synthetic link for home to some other directory the user wanted. I'm assuming that is the cause. Attempting to boot fails late in the boot process.

Comment: A conf file simply ***cannot*** do that.  There has to be a process running that does it.  Did you try running in Safe Mode as I asked?  You literally said "it's beyond me" but instead debate the issue.

Comment: I'm not debating with you, Allan, and I truly appreciate the help. I'm (attempting) to tell you what happened. This particular conf file made the system think the home directory was in some other place.That appeared to prevent it from booting. Removing that file also removed the problem. Coincidence? Perhaps. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit or remove synthetic.conf when it is causing catalina not to boot or login to your user, you must first boot into Recovery mode (hold down CMD+R during he boot sound). Then from the Utilities menu open the Terminal.

If you have FileVault enabled you will need to unlock the boot drive (there are other questions with answers on how to do this from the terminal so I wont repeat those here).

Provided that you have unlocked the boot drive you should be able to use the ‘find’ utility to locate your synthetic.conf like this:

```
cd /
find / -name synthetic.conf
```

For me it was inside a ‘private’ folder.

Then you can delete it with ‘rm’ or edit it with ‘vi’ if you’re feeling brave; I just deleted mine. Turns out that if you put spaces in it, instead of tabs, it causes your system not to boot on Catalina - What a great feature Apple :-)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Catalina on an external drive and then using the terminal I was able to navigate to the original etc directory and delete the synthetic.conf file, and then able to boot from the internal drive.

Comment: There was absolutely no need to go through such rigamarole when you could have deleted the **synthetic.conf** _file_ from the **macOS Recovery** you already had. You simple use the `find` _command_ to locate the _file_ and then delete it. Had you actually answered the questions I asked to your OP I would have given you a _fully qualified pathname_ to delete the **synthetic.conf** _file_. However, when I do not get a response to the questions I ask, I don't offer any more help!

Comment: I attempted to do that. But it seems that when booted under Mojave that's quite difficult to do. You can't even navigate to the Catalina etc directory. Once I booted into Catalina it was exactly as easy as you say. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Believe me, If I booted the **macOS Recovery** on **macOS Mojave** I could have in **Terminal** found and deleted the file in less than 5 minutes! I think you said it all when you said "I'm in over my head here. I struggle to even describe the problem."!